# Dell Optiplex 755 - serial port driver for windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, serial-port, dell-optiplex

I have a dell optiplex 755 (tower), it was shipped originally with vista but was recently reinstalled using Windows 7, 64 bit.

THe serial port driver, and something else called "PCI Simple Communications Controller" (possibly a modem on the motherboard) are listed as "other devices" in the device manager, with yellow exclamation marks in the icons meaning they have no drivers installed.

Dell does not list any drivers on their usual website where you enter your service tag.  I am pretty sure this is a standard Intel Q## chipset.  Does anybody know which one exactly, and where I can get the chipset drivers and particularly, the serial port drivers, for 64 bit Windows 7?

Comment: Yellow exclamation mark means the drivers are installed but are in an error state. Hopefully reinstalling them will solve it. Here is your driver page for that model, Dell does not offer W7 drivers, use the Vista drivers.  http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WV64&catid=-1&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=PLX_PNT_P4_755&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en&TabIndex=&scanSupported=False&scanConsent=False

Comment: The windows vista drivers install into Windows 7 but are glitchy. Not surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the drivers section on dell's site and enter your service tag:

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/index.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd

1) Install the latest chipset drivers from dell's site.
2) If that doesn't work, install the latest networking drivers from dell's site.
3) If that doesn't work, install the latest video card drivers from dell's site.

Comment: It looks like vista drivers are the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dell's support site and look up 745C drivers under "Chipset". Download the last 2 drivers and install them in your Dell driver directory under Intel PCI Driver Management. Use these to update the drivers in the Device Manager and problem fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the driver: Intel AMT SOL LMS. For the Serial Port Driver. From the driver list select Windows Vista 64 for Windows 7 / Server 2008 64-Bit.